# AQI Monitor Live Map with Google Maps API JavaScript and reading JSON from Thingspeak .getJSON and Marker

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on a program at my job where we are teaching high school students to build air quality monitors. All of the AQ monitors will send their lat, long, AQI, and temp data to Thingspeak. I want to display the location of each of the monitors and their most recent AQI numbers. I found code on github that plots the points of data using their lat longs, but it doesn't specify how to add the AQI as the label for the marker. Could just do something like this? FYI Each of the 100 monitors will have their own channel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Experiment</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




    <script>
      // Initialize global variables



      // Initialize and add the map
      function initMap() {
        // get the last location sent 

        // get LATITUDE
        $.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/fields/1/last.json?api_key=THINGSPEAKAPIKEY", function(result){

          var m = result;
          // set latitude as x
          x=Number(m.field1);

        });

        // get LONGITUDE
        $.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/fields/2/last.json?api_key=THINGSPEAKAPIKEY", function(result){

          var m = result;
          // set longitude as y
          y=Number(m.field2);

          $.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/fields/6/last.json?api_key=THINGSPEAKAPIKEY", function(result){

          var m = result;
          // set label as label
          label=String(m.field6);

        });

        }).done(function (){

          coordinates = {lat: x, lng: y};


          // The map, centered at the location given
          var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 13, center: coordinates});
          // The marker, positioned at the location given
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coordinates, 
            map: map,
            title: 'Click to get coordinates',
            label: label,
          });

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<p>Tracker Location: ' + marker.getPosition() + '</p>'
          });

          map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
            // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
            // marker.
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            }, 5000);
          });

          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            // when the marker is clicked, center map
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
          });
        });





      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLEAPIKEY&callback=initMap"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding another getJSON to pull the values from field 6, my AQI column. I tried to add label:label under marker, but that doesn't work. How do you add the label from field6? I thought the data type might have been the issue, but I changed it to String and that still isn't working. Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

The lat long fields were not included in the json from thingspeak. I manually added the lat and long from the AQ monitor and then I used the .getjson to call field6 which had the AQI. I had to convert the field to string and then add label: x, to get it to work. Now I have to figure out how to do this for all 100 without repeating code. Any suggestions are welcome.